# how to forward specific log file to a remote rsyslog server

Tags: rsyslog

I have a cassandra node (192.168.122.3) and a rsyslog server(192.168.122.2). On cassandra node, cassandra dumps its log files in /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log. I want to pull this cassandra.log file to the remote server(rsyslog server) in the /var/log/ directory. how to do it ?

Answer (score 11):

```
$ModLoad imfile    #Load the imfile input module 

$InputFilePollInterval 10 

$InputFileName  /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log 

$InputFileTag cassandra-access: 

$InputFileStateFile stat-cassandra-access 

$InputFileSeverity Info  

$InputRunFileMonitor  


$template cas_log, "  %msg% "  


if $programname == 'cassandra-access' then @@remote_server_address:port;cas_log 

if $programname == 'cassandra-access' then stop
```

Follow the following steps: 
 1) Go to /etc/rsyslog.d 
2) create a empty file named as cas-log.conf 
 3) Copy the above mentioned code and paste into this(cas-log) file. Note: replace the destination rsyslog server ip/name in second last line with  remote_server_address & port.
 4) Restart your rsyslog.
5) On sever side you can see logs in /var/log/syslog file.